# Webkit browsers, IE7 search form problem

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Here is the link to [my website](http://www.ionisedmesh.com) thats still under development. It runs well in Internet Explorer 8 and 9 as well as in Firefox. The webkit browsers (Safari and Chrome) are not able to display the facebook "like box" properly. The box goes above the dividing line. While in IE7 for some strange reason the search form doesnt `float:right`.

This is my first website so sorry for any pathetic questions:) Can u also please tell me to write a script for IE6 that would show a message to upgrade to a modern browser because IE6 absolutely messes everything up. Any other suggestions would be highly appreciated. I have used the toolbox theme for Wordpress to develop this blog.

I have used :

```
time.entry-date {color:#000; font-style:italic; text-decoration:none;}
```

To change the post date's color to black and remove the underline but the `text-decoration:none` does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Facebook follow box :**

```
#fb-root {
position:relative;
float: left;
margin-left: 10px;
/* remove: margin-top, z-index */
}
```

**HTML5 elements are not recognised by ie < 9.** Add to page `<head>`:

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

**JQuery for ie6 message:**

```
if ($.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version) =< 6) {

var here = '<a href="link-to-update.html"> here</a>';
$('body').prepend('<div id="message">Please upgrade your browser'+here+'!</div>')

}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank You for your post butthe facebook box is more out of place now in webkit browsers it has jumped on top of the jquery slider!

Comment: have you removed `style="position:absolute;..."` ?

Comment: Oh sorry i had mentioned position:absolute. Now its working great. Thanks a million!:)

Comment: can you help on one more thing. I cannot remove the Home link from the nav bar. Its not hard coded neither i could find it in the menu section in wordpress. How do i remove that?

Comment: On line 47 of your theme functions.php change `$args['show_home'] = true;` to `$args['show_home'] = false;` should do it.

Comment: Pleased to have been able to help